# How can I combine these &&, if conditions to avoid writing `-le 100` each time in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I want to write a bash script that takes in marks of 5 subjects and the marks cannot be greater than 100. How can I avoid typing `-le 100` each time.

```
while true
do
echo "enter marks of 5 subjects"
read m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
if [ $m1 -le 100 ] && [ $m2 -le 100 ] && [ $m3 -le 100 ] && [ $m4 -le 100 ] && [ $m5 -le 100 ]
then
        break
else
 echo "marks cannot be more than 100"
fi
done
```

Comment: You can read them into an array and check them all using a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I avoid typing -le 100 each time.

Well, you can type something else:

```
test_lower_equal_100() { [ "$1" -le 100 ]; }
if test_lower_equal_100 "$m1" && test_lower_equal_100 "$m2" && test_lower_equal_100 "$m3" && test_lower_equal_100 "$m4" && test_lower_equal_100 "$m5"
```

You can iterate over variables names:

```
for i in m1 m2 m3 m4 m5; do
    if [ "${!i}" -le 100 ]; then
         echo "mark $i is lower or equal to 100"
    fi
done
```

or loop over values:

```
for i in "$m1" "$m2" "$m3" "$m4" "$m5"; do
   if [ "$i" -le 100 ]; then
         echo "value $i is lower or equal to 100"
   fi
done
```

I would leave the code as it is, as it is both verbose and readable and maintainable. I would quote the variables, add `-r` to `read` and use bash arithmetic expansion `if ((m1 <= 100 && m2 <= 100 && m3 <= 100 && m4 <= 100 && m5 <= 100)); then`.